# MongoDB, Data between two Dates, records that match StartTime Irrespective of EndTime, records that match EndTime Irrespective of StartTime

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime

For Example:

```
[
    {
        "title": "test1",
        "startDate": "2022-05-16T10:56:33.005Z",
        "endDate": "2022-05-16T13:56:33.005Z",
    },
    {
        "title": "test2",
        "startDate": "2022-05-11T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2022-05-11T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
        "title": "test3",
        "startDate": "2022-05-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2022-05-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
        "title": "test4",
        "startDate": "2022-05-16T12:00:33.005Z",
        "endDate": "2022-05-16T13:56:33.005Z",
    },
    {
        "title": "test5",
        "startDate": "2022-05-16T11:00:33.005Z",
        "endDate": "2022-05-16T15:56:33.005Z",
    },
    {
        "title": "test6",
        "startDate": "2022-05-16T14:50:33.005Z",
        "endDate": "2022-05-17T01:50:33.005Z",
    }
]
```

,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of my research, I found the answer

```
query = {
$or: [
    { // inbetween
    $and: [
            { startDate: { $gte: new Date(data.from_date)
                }
            },
            { endDate: { $lte: new Date(data.to_date)
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    { // 3 to 5 ----- 1 to 4 hours

    $and: [
            { startDate: { $lte: new Date(data.from_date)
                }
            },
            { endDate: { $gte: new Date(data.from_date)
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    { // 3 to 5 ---- 4 to 8 hours
    $and: [
            { startDate: { $lte: new Date(data.to_date)
                }
            },
            { endDate: { $gte: new Date(data.to_date)
                }
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer:
[
{
"title": "test1",
"startDate": "2022-05-16T10:56:33.005Z",
"endDate": "2022-05-16T13:56:33.005Z",
},
{
"title": "test4",
"startDate": "2022-05-16T12:00:33.005Z",
"endDate": "2022-05-16T13:56:33.005Z",
},
{
"title": "test5",
"startDate": "2022-05-16T11:00:33.005Z",
"endDate": "2022-05-16T15:56:33.005Z",
},
{
"title": "test6",
"startDate": "2022-05-16T14:50:33.005Z",
"endDate": "2022-05-17T01:50:33.005Z",
}
],